# How to exchange values between specific keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say you have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {
    'A': 'content_for_A',
    'B': 'content_for_B'
}
```

What is the most efficient way to swap the values between the two entries? So the result should be like this:

```
d = {
    'A': 'content_for_B',
    'B': 'content_for_A'
}
```

Of course, you can create a new dictionary `d2` and do `d2['A'] = d['B']; d2['B'] = d['A']` but is this the recommended way or is there an efficient way without the need to create a new dictionary?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
d['A'], d['B'] = d['B'], d['A']
```

Tuple unpacking is a great tool in Python to swap the values of two objects without the need of creating an intermediary variable.

Comment: Hah, I'm actually familiar with this syntax but wasn't aware that this also works for dictionaries. Even though I know Python pretty well, the language still surprises me from time to time. :) Thank you.

Comment: @PeterStahl it works for anything you can assign something to `;)`

Answer (score 0):

#### {'1': '1', '2': None, '3': '3'}

Expected

#### {'1': '3', '2': None, '3': '1'}

#### Solution

```
dict([(key, num) for (key, _), num in zip(your_dict.items(), reversed(list(your_dict.values())))])
```